# DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(...) not working in liferay server

Tags: liferay, liferay-6.2

DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFileAsStream(...) not working in my server I have s3 configuration for document and media. This method perfectly working without any issue in local server where s3 not configured. Does this require any extra configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I basically want to convert DLFileEntry into File so I had used another method.

File file = DLFileEntryLocalServiceUtil.getFile(user.getUserId(),dlFileEntry.getFileEntryId(), dlFileEntry.getVersion(), true);